# webhosting on cloud Azure/Aws

Tags: mysql, wordpress, azure, amazon-web-services, cloud

Hi guys need your help for web hosting my website on cloud (Azure/Aws). I have a wordpress website with 100 users/day,mysql database max size 100GB. I am Planing to use Iaas but I am open to Pass also.

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what exactly your question is. You should state an explicit question. Also this might not be the best site to ask your question as stackoverflow is for programming problems. Maybe you should ask your question at https://serverfault.com/

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Azure offers several ways to host web sites: Azure App Service, Virtual Machines, Service Fabric, and Cloud Services.

Azure App Service is the best choice for most web apps. Deployment and management are integrated into the platform, sites can scale quickly to handle high traffic loads, and the built-in load balancing and traffic manager provide high availability.

There are [3 steps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2017/04/28/wordpress-migration-easy-as-a-b-c-1-2-3/) to migrating a WordPress website to Azure App Service Web Apps.
1.  Copy WordPress files
2.  Migrate the MySQL Database
3.  Configure WordPress

The [Azure App Service Migration site and the tool](https://www.migratetoazure.net/) can be utilized to migrate sites from Windows and Linux web servers to Azure App Service. As part of the migration the tool will create Web Apps and databases on Azure if needs be, publish content and publish your database.

Reference: [Azure App Service, Virtual Machines, Service Fabric, and Cloud Services comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm)